Photon Spin and Fermionic Fields
I have a question. It is said that the photon has spin 1. However, the spin of a fermion like the electron is 1/2. What I see is that the fermionic field has 4 fields,
$$ \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1} \\ \psi_{2} \\ \psi_{3} \\ \psi_{4} \end{pmatrix} $$
Where
$$ \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_{1} \\ \psi_{2} \end{pmatrix} $$
represents the spin-up and spin-down components, respectively, of the electron.
$$ \psi = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_{3} \\ \psi_{4} \end{pmatrix} $$
represents the spin-up and spin-down components, respectively, of the positron.
Why is it said that the photon has spin 1 if it has 2 components like the electron and the positron? What would be the components of the photon field? Because they are not the electric field or the magnetic field, but I believe it is an electromagnetic field with right-handed rotation and another with left-handed rotation. Is that correct?

You are confusing four-vectors with Dirac spinors. The Lorentz group acts on the former while $\text{Spin}^\mathbb{C}(1,3)$ acts on the latter. $\text{Spin}^\mathbb{C}(1,3)$ is the complexification of the double cover of the Lorentz group. To be short, Dirac spinors are pairs of spinors, so two objects in the same box, while a four-vector is one object.

Thanks. So, you are saying that we can represents a fermion with a pairs of spinors but we can not represents the electromagnetic field with a pair of spinors, we need to use the four-vector. It is correct?

Yes, this is correct

Photons are indeed spin-1 objects and are as such represented at every space-time point by 4-vector like objects as $A_\mu$. However, due to gauge symmetry and the fact that photons are massless, it is possible to show that these 4 degrees of freedom can be reduced to only 2 independent ones (i.e. it is possible to find relation between them), such that the state of the photon field can be fully described by the two degrees of freedom you are referring to (the photon's helicity). More on this e.g. here: Number of degrees of freedom of a photon.
As you correctly said, fermion fields are spin $1/2$ and are thus represented by the 2 component objects you are mentioning (Weyl spinors). Combining the two Weyl spinors (of electron and positron) into a 4 component Dirac bispinor defines a new object allowing to express the evolution of both fields with the single Dirac equation.
In more technical terms, representations of the Lorentz group are characterized by two half integers $(j_1,j_2)$. What we commonly call the "spin" of the representation is given by $s=j_1+j_2$.
General 4-vectors belong to the spin-1 $(1/2,1/2)$ representation, but the electromagnetic field can also be characterized by the 2-form $F$ transforming under the composite representation $(1,0)\oplus (0,1)$ (which as you can see, is also of spin-1). The doublet of photon helicity itself can also be associated with a specific representation of something known as "the little group" but I am far from expert on this. More infos here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics).
Each Weyl spinor belongs respectively to $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$, while Dirac bispinor belongs to the composite $(1/2,0)\oplus (0,1/2)$ representation of the Lorentz group.
Find more info on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group
